# What does it mean to have a valid record when the record contains nothing, not even a single space

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-analysis

I was browsing the data for a particular column which looked like it had spaces because it did not say `null`

Upon trying to find what it was, I discovered the data does not have a single space but it is also not blank.

What is it then?  -- something between two single quotations '' which is not space.

Tried to run this query with no results:

```
select column1 from table1 where column1 like '% %' 
-- Single space
```

-> `No records found`

The second query I tried (see below) has no spaces mentioned. And that gave a result saying that there exist records which are like ->`''`

```
select column1 from table1 where column1 like '% %'

select column1 from table1 where column1= ''
```

I am trying to understand what is that record and what does it mean to be nothing?

Comment: There are many [unicode whitespace characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) other than the ASCII 32 space character. You might be able to find out what it is using `select convert_to(column1, 'SQL_ASCII') from table1`.  The output will show the hexadecimal representation of the underlying data.

Comment: Try to cast it to `bytea` like `SELECT column1::bytea FROM table1 WHERE ...;`. That should give you a string showing the actual bytes. Then you can continue to search what that could be from there.

Comment: A string can have zero length just like a cup can have 0 milliliters of water in it

Comment: @unutbu Thank you for the response. I tried converting it and the message it displayed was that it is a 'binary code' and apparently I cannot see it - maybe because it is quite big? However, I was just analyzing so the main job is done

Comment: @CaiusJard I understand your point. I was not sure if a data could be of zero length. Upon converting I found there was some binary code in it and cannot be comprehended in ASCII

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is it then? -- something between two single quotations '' which is not space.

It's a string of zero length. You're right, it's not a space - a space is `' '` - it has a length of one character. A string of length 0 is nothing like a string of length 1, no matter what character is in the string.

In any computer system we arbitrarily decide on the meaning of everything. Suppose you have a question that has an answer A, B, or C. You might also have situations where the person doesn't know, or knows but doesn't want to say. You might arbitrarily decide to have NULL means "don't know" and 0 length string as "don't want to say" in addition to all the people who do answer with a letter

This is an arbitrary decision, maybe you decide to store a space for "don't want to say", maybe an exclamation mark- whatever. Some database vendors think it is important to provide support for having strings of zero length, others (oracle) do not (oracle treats null and '' as the same)

Ultimately if your db supports zero length strings you have to understand what they are and in the context of your application you have to understand what they mean. What they are is like a glass with no water in it, or a bag of sweets with no sweets in it.. The statement of "there is no data" is different to "we don't know if there is any data or not" - the uncertainty here is more often associated with NULL

> I am trying to understand what is that record and what does it mean to be nothing?

That record is a record with a zero length string in that column. However, we cannot tell you what it means because the decision to store a zero length string in it was taken by you or one of the other developers at your company, or a previous developer who quit. It could be that he wanted to record a difference between null and zero data. It could be that he couldn't be bothered checking if the data was null and wanted to avoid a typical null reference crash on the front end app. It could be that he wanted to count the data even though there was no data to put there

We cannot answer this part of your question

We can only tell you that zero length strings are possible, you can attach as much meaning to them as any other string, and they will never be equal to a string of non zero length so `like '% %'` will never find them. Do not assume that something you cannot see must be a space..

Comment: That's a great learning curve for me. The main reason I thought it was a white space because of the kind of data I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

Nullable Text fields be either `NULL` or a string of length 0, i.e. `''` or a non-empty string, eg. `'abc'`

`''` is not the same as `NULL`.

I was taught in my databases course that `NULL` signifies that the value is unkown, and an *identity* value, such as an empty string, would mean that we know the value and it is nothing, but often developers and applications don't respect this distinction.

Comment: You were taught wrong in your database class.  `NULL` is often used for missing.  But the semantics in SQL generally assume that `NULL` means "unknown".  In my opinion, "missing" would have been a better choice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks. I think you're right & the course probably taught `unknown` or `undefined`, which I've internalized as `missing`. answer updated.

Comment: *'' is not the same as null* is very much a decision taken by the database vendor rather than a hard and fast rule. For example, Oracle treats empty strings as null, SQLserver does not

Comment: @CaiusJard, it all depends on what philosophies are used for both strings and nulls. Codd later recognised that there are at least two different senses in which null is regularly used - applicable but missing/unknown, and inapplicable/irrelevant - but employing his four-valued logic system rigourously is found to be too difficult in practice.